# Setting PGPASSWORD environment variable for Postgres (psql) process executed by Inno Setup

Tags: postgresql, environment-variables, inno-setup

I need to create a PostgreSQL [tablespace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) with [Inno Setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Running this on the command line works:

```
SET PGPASSWORD=P0stgres
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -c "CREATE TABLESPACE TABLETEST OWNER postgres LOCATION E'{app}\\PATHTEST\\Db'"
```

But trying this in Inno Setup does not work:

```
[Run]
Filename: {sys}\cmd.exe; Parameters: "SET PGPASSWORD=P0stgres"
Filename: {sys}\cmd.exe; Parameters: ""C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -c "CREATE TABLESPACE TABLETEST OWNER postgres LOCATION E'{app}\\PATHTEST\\Db'""
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it work. Was a little mistake.
The correct is:

```
[Run]
Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/K SET PGPASSWORD=P0stgres&""C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe"" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -c ""CREATE TABLESPACE TABLETEST OWNER postgres LOCATION '{app}\PATHTEST\Db'""
```

Comment: Would mind telling us, what was that "little" mistake? The space before the `&`?

Answer (score 5):

I am able to do it. There should be no space between `password` and &`.` `PGPASSWORD=password&`

```
Filename: "cmd.exe"; Parameters: "/c set PGPASSWORD=my_db_user& ""psql"" -U my_db_user -d myappdb -a -q -f C:\my\Manager\SQL\Sequences.sql & pause"; Flags: runascurrentuser;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems:

- [The `cmd.exe` needs `/C` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) before the command.
- The environment variable is not magically exported to the second `cmd.exe` instance that runs the `psql.exe`. You have to execute both commands within the same `cmd.exe` instance. One of the ways is using `&` "operator" (another way is using a wrapper batch file to execute both commands).
- The double-quotes (particularly those around the `C:\...\psql.exe` and `CREATE TABLESPACE ...`) [have to be doubled](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params).
- Not a problem per se, but you should better use [`{cmd}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=cmd) instead of `{sys}\cmd.exe`.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C SET PGPASSWORD=P0stgres& ""C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe"" -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres -c ""CREATE TABLESPACE TABLETEST OWNER postgres LOCATION E'{app}\\PATHTEST\\Db'"""
```